# Gravatar in ASP.Net WebForms showing default image

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, gravatar

I have embeded an AjaxToolKit Gravatar in a blog comment foreach loop. The Gravatar's email address is not representing the actual value of the email address, but is rather the literal string (blue font) CommentEmail. I've tried a multitude of syntax options, with no success as yet. Here is the code as it stands:

```
<div class="comments">
    <div>
        <h3>Comments</h3>
    </div>

        <%  foreach (System.Data.DataRow myCRow in myCommentDataTable.Rows)
            {
                string CommentID = myCRow[0].ToString();
                string BlogParentID = myCRow[1].ToString();
                string Commenter = myCRow[2].ToString();
                string CommenterEmail = myCRow[3].ToString();
                string Comment = myCRow[4].ToString();
                string CommentDate = myCRow[5].ToString();
                if (BlogParentID == Id)
                {
                    Response.Write("<div class='commentdate pull-right'>" + CommentDate + "</div>");
                    Response.Write("<div class='commenter'>" + Commenter + "</div><br />");
                    Response.Write("<p>" + Comment + "</p>");
                    %><Ajax:Gravatar runat='server' ID='GravatarImage' Email='<%= CommenterEmail  %> ' DefaultImageBehavior='MysteryMan' /><br /><br /><%
                }
            }%>
</div>
```

CommenterEmail in the very last line is the offending text.  It displays as a string in blue font rather than the variable in black font. So it evaluates as an invalid email address and shows the default "myster man" icon.  If I hard code my email address there, it works properly, displaying my Gravatar for all users.

What is the proper syntax for embedding that email value in the AjaxToolKit:Gravatar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two weeks of battling with the Ajax Gravatar control, I have come to the conclusion that it simply does not work for a dynamically generated email address.

I have implemented it as follows...

In the aspx:

```
<div class="comments">
    <div>
        <h3>Comments</h3>
    </div>
        <%
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow myCRow in myCommentDataTable.Rows)
            {
                string CommentID = myCRow[0].ToString();
                string BlogParentID = myCRow[1].ToString();
                string Commenter = myCRow[2].ToString();
                string CommenterEmail = myCRow[3].ToString().ToLower().Trim();
                string Comment = myCRow[4].ToString();
                string CommentDate = myCRow[5].ToString();

                if (BlogParentID == Id)
                {
                    //  Compute the hash
                    string hash = HashEmailForGravatar(CommenterEmail);
                    //  Assemble the url and return
                    string myGravatar = string.Format("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}?size=50", hash);
                    Response.Write("<div class='commentdate pull-right'>" + CommentDate + "</div>");
                    Response.Write("<div class='commenter'>");
                    Response.Write("<img src='" + myGravatar + "' alt='" + Commenter + "' />&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                    Response.Write(Commenter + "</div>");
                    Response.Write("<p>" + Comment + "</p>");

                }
            }%>
</div>
```

In the codebehind:

```
public static string HashEmailForGravatar(string email)
{
    // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.  
    MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

    // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.  
    byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(email));

    // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes  
    // and create a string.  
    System.Text.StringBuilder sBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    // Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
    // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.  
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sBuilder.ToString();  // Return the hexadecimal string. 
}
```

[Dan's Blog](https://www.danesparza.net/2010/10/using-gravatar-images-with-c-asp-net/)